# Multiple grouping SQL, clicks and users count wrong

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by

im trying to get the count of clicks/users to my website, to do that i have their cookie id and date. but from the queries that i have written so far i get the following errors

table

```
cookieid  date      
--------------------
001       2011-03-17          
001       2011-03-17         
002       2011-03-17          
001       2011-03-17          
001       2011-03-20
002       2011-03-21    
114       2011-03-21          
114       2011-03-21
```

the precise way the count should indicate is:

```
on 2011-03-17 => 4 clicks / 2 unique visitors
on 2011-03-20 => 1 click  / 1 unique visitor   
on 2011-03-21 => 3 clicks / 2 unique visitors
```

If i do like below in the query

```
"INSERT INTO visitos SELECT cookieid,date FROM ",@tab," GROUP BY cookieid"
```

this gives the correct count on clicks/users by counting correctly but it ignores the date, according to the table above it will tell 2011-03-17 => 4 clicks / 2 unique visitors but it ignores the clicks/visiting on 20th and gives no count for 20th. because the cookie id is repeating

with another way

```
"INSERT INTO visitos SELECT cookieid,date FROM ",@tab," GROUP BY date"
```

It will give all the dates with clicks/visiting but outcome of the counts are wrong,
it will tell 2011-03-17 => 4 clicks / 4 unique visitors by getting every click as a unique user while ignoring the cookie id

can anybody help me on writing the SQL query to group this by both cookie id and the date at once

```
P.S "INSERT INTO visitos SELECT cookieid,date FROM ",@tab," GROUP BY date,cookieid"
```

did not work either

**the stored proceedure**

```
BEGIN
SET @tab = CONCAT("monitortable_",pr);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS uniquevisitors;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE uniquevisitors (`cookieid` INT, `date` DATETIME);


**SET @sqlstring = CONCAT("(PLACE WHERE GROUPING QUERY SHOULD TAKE PLACE)INSERT INTO uniquevisitors SELECT cookieid,date FROM ",@tab," GROUP BY cookieid");**


PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlstring;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS uniquevisitorscount;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE uniquevisitorscount (`cnt` INT, `dat` DATETIME);
INSERT INTO uniquevisitorscount SELECT COUNT(cookieid) AS cnt ,DATE(date) AS dat FROM uniquevisitors;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS nonuniquevisitcount;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE nonuniquevisitcount (`cnt` INT, `dat` DATETIME);
SET @sqlstring = CONCAT("INSERT INTO nonuniquevisitcount SELECT COUNT(cookieid) AS cnt ,DATE(date) AS dat 

FROM ",@tab," GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%y'),DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m'),DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d')");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlstring;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    SELECT un.cnt AS ucnt, nu.cnt AS cnt, un.dat AS dat FROM uniquevisitorscount un JOIN nonuniquevisitcount nu ON un.dat = nu.dat;
END$$
```

Comment: Could you please retag your question and decide for mysql OR sql-server?

Comment: So the difference between COUNT() and COUNT(DISTINCT )?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

"INSERT INTO visitos date,count(cookie_id) no_of_clicks,count(distinct cookie_id) no_of_visitors  FROM ",@tab," GROUP BY date "

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select x.date, sum(x.cnt) as clicks, count(*) as uniqueVisitors from
    (select date, cookieid, count(*) as cnt from #temp group by date, cookieid) x 
    group by x.date
```

returns this:

```
date        clicks  uniqueVisitors
2011-03-17  4       2
2011-03-20  1       1
2011-03-21  3       2
```

exactly as you wanted ... you just have to create an insert statement from this ...

Comment: thanks i found it helpful... but my query is inside a stored proceedure... i found it hard to match it with your... can you help me on adding it to the stored proceedure

Comment: I don't understand your stored procedure at all ... just saw that your question is about MySQL ... thought you were using ms sql server ... guess my query won't even work with MySQL ... sorry